# How to fix 'Connection reset by ip port 443'

Tags: git, github

I use git via my Windows PC. Everytimes I try `git push` or other git commands with educational internet or personal internet, it will return `Push failed
            Connection reset by 192.30.253.122 port 443
            Could not read from remote repository.
            Please make sure you have the correct access rights
            and the repository exists.`

So I have to use mobile phone's hotspot, pushing succeeds. I don't want to use HTTPS to use git. If port 443 is used or forbidden, what should I do?

Comment: Does the server support SSH?

Comment: Yes. Actually, if I `git push` as soon as I connect to edutional internet, it works. But minutes later, the only way to use git is use my hotspot.

Comment: What is "educational internet" vs "personal internet"? Are those private networks where you work? If so then you probably need to talk to the administrators of those networks. It sure does look strange though, you can't block https in todays internet age, as then nothing should work.

Comment: "Educational Internet" means Internet provided by my university, and "personal Internet" means the Internet at my home. We all know that there's 2 ways to clone a repo, SSH and HTTPS. I believe the former is better.

Answer (score 0):

Сontact internet administrator. This port appears to be blocked by firewall.

Comment: On the Internet provided by my university, it maybe work. But the error ocors even on the internet at my home provided by telecommunications company. As far as I know, it has no administrator. It's really strange.